# [vertx.redis.client]No handler waiting for message

Tags: redis, vert.x

**Version**

vert.x core:3.5.0

vert.x redis client:3.5.0

**Context**

2018-06-02 17:40:55.981 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: 14751915

2018-06-02 17:41:10.937 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: false

2018-06-02 17:41:10.947 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: false

2018-06-02 17:41:20.937 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: true

2018-06-02 17:41:30.937 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: true

2018-06-02 17:41:35.927 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: false

2018-06-02 17:41:40.937 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: true

2018-06-02 17:41:50.948 ERROR 4933 --- [ntloop-thread-2] io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnection      : No handler waiting for message: true

**After view code of the io.vertx.redis.impl.RedisConnectioni find the why:**

1. When server started, create redis connetion,it's ok for runing.
2. After long time (eg.days),the state of connection is DISCONNECTED. Vert.x redis client reconnect redis server when send command to redis server:

```
      void send(final Command command) {

    // start the handshake if not connected
    if (state.get() == State.DISCONNECTED) {
      connect();
    }
```

3. connect() call clearQueue()
4. clearQueue(): waiting command quene will be empty.
5. Call handleReply() when receive from redis server with new connection.

**note: An error log appears here**(the third line to bottom).

```
      private void handleReply(Reply reply) {
        final Command cmd = waiting.poll();

        if (cmd != null) {
          switch (reply.type()) {
            case '-': // Error
              cmd.handle(Future.failedFuture(reply.asType(String.class)));
              return;
            case '+':   // Status
              switch (cmd.responseTransform()) {
                case ARRAY:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new JsonArray().add(reply.asType(String.class))));
                  break;
                default:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(reply.asType(cmd.returnType())));
                  break;
              }
              return;
            case '$':  // Bulk
              switch (cmd.responseTransform()) {
                case ARRAY:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new JsonArray().add(reply.asType(String.class, cmd.encoding()))));
                  break;
                case INFO:
                  String info = reply.asType(String.class, cmd.encoding());

                  if (info == null) {
                    cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(null));
                  } else {
                    String lines[] = info.split("\\r?\\n");
                    JsonObject value = new JsonObject();

                    JsonObject section = null;
                    for (String line : lines) {
                      if (line.length() == 0) {
                        // end of section
                        section = null;
                        continue;
                      }

                      if (line.charAt(0) == '#') {
                        // begin section
                        section = new JsonObject();
                        // create a sub key with the section name
                        value.put(line.substring(2).toLowerCase(), section);
                      } else {
                        // entry in section
                        int split = line.indexOf(':');
                        if (section == null) {
                          value.put(line.substring(0, split), line.substring(split + 1));
                        } else {
                          section.put(line.substring(0, split), line.substring(split + 1));
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(value));
                  }
                  break;
                default:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(reply.asType(cmd.returnType(), cmd.encoding())));
                  break;
              }
              return;
            case '*': // Multi
              switch (cmd.responseTransform()) {
                case HASH:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(reply.asType(JsonObject.class, cmd.encoding())));
                  break;
                default:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(reply.asType(JsonArray.class, cmd.encoding())));
                  break;
              }
              return;
            case ':':   // Integer
              switch (cmd.responseTransform()) {
                case ARRAY:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new JsonArray().add(reply.asType(Long.class))));
                  break;
                default:
                  cmd.handle(Future.succeededFuture(reply.asType(cmd.returnType())));
                  break;
              }
              return;
            default:
              cmd.handle(Future.failedFuture("Unknown message type"));
          }
        } else {
          // **An error log appears here**
          log.error("No handler waiting for message: " + reply.asType(String.class));
        }
      }
```

**question:**

It's a bug or not?
If not a bug , the post commands will be discarded when reconnect redis server.

What's a good way to deal with this situation?

Comment: I think the best for now is to downgrade the logging from `error` to `warn` or `info` as this should be be critical. On the other hand the redis client is being refactored to remove the "magic" connection handling giving you the full control on the connection state.

Comment: I agree with you, I think the best way at present is to modify the source code, there are two ways to modify:<br/>

1. Automatic reconnection is prohibited.<br/>

2. Continue to allow automatic reconnection, but do not purge queues, while ensuring that the command execution context is consistent.<br/>

The first one is easy to implement, but the previous command will be lost.<br/>

The second major difficulty is to ensure that the command context is consistent after the connection is repeated.<br/>

Comment: The purge is necessary because on reconnect the state from the server is lost and all waiting handlers would remain there forever, which would cause a memory leak

Comment: But something seems strange :
After reconnect redis server, who call handleReply() when waiting quene is empty ?
From code execution It seems that the new connection replaces the old connection and returns the server's response information(for old connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The reason for the above problem is that the connection has been reused and has not been closed. The solution is:
`

```
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create(this.vertx, redisOptions);
//do some thing; 
redisClient.close(h-{})...
```

` 
for each session.